# Python write a function that selects the smallest number from a list of 10 randomly generated numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function generates a list of 10 random numbers. I need to modify this function to select and print the smallest number from the randomly generated list Please help, I am having a very hard time with it:

```
import random
my_randoms=[]
for i in range (10):
    my_randoms.append(random.randrange(1,101,1))

print (my_randoms)
```

Comment: `min(my_randoms)`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) function for O(n) complexity

```
min(my_randoms)
```

Comment: added min() as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use numpy

```
import numpy as np

np.random.randint(1, 101, 10).min()
```

Short explanation:

```
np.random.randint(1, 101, 10)
```

will print something like this

```
array([91, 57, 53, 26, 95,  9, 31, 47, 29, 78])
```

and then you just access the minimum value with `min()`.

In your implementation you would just do

```
min(my_randoms)
```

as @Austin mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like some sort of homework assignment. If you need to make minimum number of changes to the existing function and you need to *find minimum yourself* (without calling built-in functions), then I would suggest:

```
In [14]: import random
    ...: my_randoms=[]
    ...: minv = None
    ...: for i in range (10):
    ...:     my_randoms.append(random.randrange(1,101,1))
    ...:     if minv is None:
    ...:         minv = my_randoms[-1]
    ...:     elif my_randoms[-1] < minv:
    ...:         minv = my_randoms[-1]
    ...: 
    ...: print (my_randoms)
    ...: print(minv)
    ...: 
[94, 24, 79, 75, 12, 57, 39, 37, 7, 96]
7
```

Even better, but at the expense of modifying/restructuring function's code:

```
In [15]: import random
    ...: minv = random.randrange(1,101,1)
    ...: my_randoms = [minv]
    ...: for i in range (9):
    ...:     v = random.randrange(1,101,1)
    ...:     my_randoms.append(v)
    ...:     if v < minv:
    ...:         minv = v
    ...: 
    ...: print (my_randoms)
    ...: print(minv)
    ...: 
[67, 33, 2, 83, 66, 93, 51, 57, 43, 55]
2
```

If you are allowed to use built-in functions, then simply call `min(my_randoms)` as suggested by [@Aran-Frey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637158/python-write-a-function-that-selects-the-smallest-number-from-a-list-of-10-rando/50637935#comment88284469_50637240).